# jQuery Autocomplete Not showing all results from query

Tags: mysql, jquery-autocomplete

i am using jQuery auto complete to view results as drop down as user types, in my case i am getting user names from database to show,

```
 <?php 
          foreach ($stmt = $link->query('select u.id, u.display_name  from user u inner join accounts a on u.id=a.uid  where a.account_type !="bot" order by u.display_name ASC') as $value) 
          {
            ?>
              display_name.push('<?php echo $value["display_name"] ?>');
              user_id.push('<?php echo $value["id"] ?>');
        <?php 
          }
        ?>
```

the problem here is, alot of names are like o'livia or de'silva, this extra `'` is causing the query to behave unexpectedly, it does not show results and instead prints this error message.

```
 user_id.push('5648');
 display_name.push('Boody L'Dally');
 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

while i know i am not formatting my query right, i have tried a lot of options but of no use, any idea how to bring all the names correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your string just include only ' never " ... so can solve like below ..
user_id.push('5648');
display_name.push("Boody L'Dally");

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the data coming from the database.
There are many functions to escape data and it's worth reading into further.
Here's an example for you:

```
display_name.push('<?= htmlspecialchars($value["display_name"]) ?>');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function autocomplet() {
    var min_length = 0;
    var keyword = $('#country_id').val();
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax_refresh.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#country_list_id').show();
                $('#country_list_id').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#country_list_id').hide();
    }
}


function set_item(item) {
    // change input value
    $('#country_id').val(item);
    // hide proposition list
    $('#country_list_id').hide();
}
```